# Hashbytes com valor diferentes ao fazer select e gravar com update

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, select, sql-update, md5

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5','123')
```

Esse select acima me retorna o seguinte resultado: `0x202CB962AC59075B964B07152D234B70`

Porém quando eu faço um update na tabela usando o mesmo hashbytes

```
UPDATE USUARIOSLOGADOS SET TOKENSESSAO = HASHBYTES('MD5','123') WHERE CODIGOUSUARIO = 1
```

o valor que fica gravado é esse : `,¹b¬Y[–K-#Kp`

Era pra gravar o mesmo resultado do primeiro exemplo, porém não é assim que rola... Alguém sabe porque ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri pessoal:
O problema era que meu datatype no banco de dados era `varchar`.
Realizando uns testes vi que o tipo correto que o hashbytes retorna é `varbinary`.
fiz a alteração e funcionou certinho.